i am encountering err_connection_closed while fetching https in mikrotik router
encoutering an error "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" in my browser console. So basically am trying to start a wifi hotspot venture and am using mikrotik 951ui 2hnd v.6.49.1 with custom captive portal and in the portal files i have an external URL to fetch some data i.e payment gateway to which i have deployed on cloud. So what can i do to solve this issue, cause i have tried requesting the URL from locally from my PC and it works fine but from the router its not working. Thanks
My main aim is to fetch https using the URL to the portal from the Mikrotik Router
